# jQuery Toggle Script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with different tables showing values in centimeters and inches 
Initially my tables are populated with inches

There is a button that you can click and then it changes the table to show values in centimeter

As you can see the way my code is built, is that each table will have it own button to changes inches to cm and vice versa.

What I'm looking for is clicking on one of the button will change all the value for all the tables. If someone click on button that's located in table 2 to see centimeters then change all the tables to be in centimeters. The button is nested within each of the 4 DIVs that contains my tables. would you done this?

```
<a class="unitpicker on" href="#"></a> 

jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    jQuery('#Laura .unitpicker').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('on');
    jQuery('#Laura .imperial').toggle();
    jQuery('#Laura .metric').toggle();
});

jQuery('#Petites .unitpicker').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('on');
    jQuery('#Petites .metric').toggle();
    jQuery('#Petites .imperial').toggle();
});

jQuery('#Plus .unitpicker').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('on');
    jQuery('#Plus .metric').toggle();
    jQuery('#Plus .imperial').toggle();
});

jQuery('#PlusPetites .unitpicker').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('on');
    jQuery('#PlusPetites .metric').toggle();
    jQuery('#PlusPetites .imperial').toggle();
});
```

Comment: would you mind showing us your HTML as well? Possibly make a jsfiddle?

Comment: If you want one button to change all tables then just refer to `table .metric` .... instead of including the ID. All can change based on where you want the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[JSBIN DEMO](http://jsbin.com/azudeyo/1/edit)**

```
jQuery(function( $ ){ // DOM ready and secured $ alias

    // Collect every button with class .unitpicker
    var $unitBtns = $('.unitpicker');

    $unitBtns.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $unitBtns.toggleClass('on');      // toggle class on every button
        $('.imperial, .metric').toggle(); // swap names
    });

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Start by grouping the code of the click function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    jQuery('.unitpicker').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('on');
        jQuery('#'+this.id+' .metric').toggle();
        jQuery('#'+this.id+' .imperial').toggle();
    });
});
```